# I have written code in JavaScript for dotted pagination. I want this code to be optimised and improved. How can I achieve it?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, pagination

I want to have this code under 20 lines somehow not by writing it in one line but by improving some logic in it and it contains multiple if conditions which I want to remove or make it less or if I can remove all the if conditions and have recursive function at that place. So, If there is any way to do it then please help me out.

This code is of around 150 lines before I am optimising it for around 5 days now and now I got it this much less but I want it more optimized. The code is working perfectly fine I just want it to be optimised.

```
let start = 1,
    limit = 1,
    totalcount = 12 / limit,
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function loadDoc(start) {
    request.onload = function() {
        let dataArr = JSON.parse(this.response).data,
            table = "";
        for (let i in dataArr) {
            table += "<tbody><tr>";
            table += "<td>"+ dataArr[i].id +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ dataArr[i].first_name +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ dataArr[i].last_name +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ dataArr[i].email +"</td>";
            table += "<td><img alt='' " + "src=" + dataArr[i].avatar + "></td>";
            table += "</tr></tbody>";
        }
        document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = table;
    };
    request.open('GET', 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=' + start + '&per_page=' + limit, true);
    request.send();

    function rebuildPagination(start, totalcount) {
        let HTML = "";
        HTML += addButton("1", start);
        if (start > 3) HTML += "<button disabled>...</button>";
        if (start === totalcount) HTML += addButton(start - 2, start);
        if (start > 2) HTML += addButton(start - 1, start);
        if (start !== 1 && start !== totalcount) HTML += addButton(start, start);
        if (start < totalcount - 1) HTML += addButton(start + 1, start);
        if (start === 1) HTML += addButton(start + 2, start);
        if (start < totalcount - 2) HTML += "<button disabled>...</button>";
        HTML += addButton(totalcount, start);
        document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = HTML;
    }
    rebuildPagination(start, totalcount);
}

function addButton(number) {
    return "<button onclick=loadDoc(" + number + ")>" + (number) + "</button>";
}
```

This code is of around 42 lines written properly I want to have this code under 20 lines somehow not by writing it in one line but by improving some logic in it and it contains multiple if conditions which I want to remove or make it less.

Comment: Don't worry about the lines that are HTML, but *at least* use template literals for mult-line readability. You also might consider using event delegation and checking the DOM instead of using inline attribute handlers, they're generally considered to be quite poor practice

Comment: are you talking about brackets for If conditions?

Comment: I'm talking about the `table += "<tbody><tr>";`-like lines, and the `addButton` function

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit, but please read their rules too

Comment: Can you please Provide me an example about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have too many tbodies. This is shorter
`let table= []; dataArr.forEach(el => table.push(\`<tr><td>${el.id}</td><td>${el.first_name}</td>${el.last_name}</td><td>${el.email}</td><td><img alt="" src="${el.avatar}"/></td></tr>\`) );
  document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = table.join("")`

Comment: It is throwing an error that table.join("") is not a function.

Comment: table must be a narray table=[]

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks!! Any more suggestions please?

Comment: why must the code have less lines? Why do you create the HTML table using strings instead of the DOM?

Comment: There is no particular reason behind the code with less lines. I just want the code to be more effective and precise with good logic and for the table I just changed it to the array instead of strings. I just mainly want to merge the if conditions which I am using to make pagination or if I can remove the if conditions and use recursive functions or anything else instead of that then also it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your code and what you are trying to do. Please notice that the number of lines does not say anything about the efficiency of code. The most important points about good coding is:

- Your code is readable and well formatted
- You should prefer object representations over strings (in your case better use the DOM)
- Try to think about using loops instead of duplicated code.

If you want to minimize your code to decrease loading time, use a [minimizer](https://javascript-minifier.com/). I recommended you to use an IDE or an Text Editor that allows Syntax highlighting and code reformatting. (last one is very important to automatically indent code)
If you can, use [jquery](https://jquery.com/).

If you need help in the future, please tell us what your code should do. Without it it's very hard to get it from your code snippet.

```js
    let limit = 10,
        paginationStart = 1,
        paginationEnd = 1,
        numberOfPages = 15,
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        actualPage = 1;

    const dummyData = [{
        avatar: "https://miro.medium.com/max/1080/1*HvFeV6SKhiW2YFEWAvQVEQ.jpeg",
        id: 1,
        first_name: "John",
        last_name: "Doe",
        email: "johndoe@example.com"
    },
        {
            avatar: "https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/173/576/Wat8.jpg?1315930535",
            id: 2,
            first_name: "Tina",
            last_name: "Doe",
            email: "tinadoe@example.com"
        },
        {
            avatar: "https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/173/576/Wat8.jpg?1315930535",
            id: 3,
            first_name: "Tina",
            last_name: "Doe",
            email: "tinadoe@example.com"
        },
        {
            avatar: "https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/173/576/Wat8.jpg?1315930535",
            id: 4,
            first_name: "Tina",
            last_name: "Doe",
            email: "tinadoe@example.com"
        }];

    function loadDoc() {
        document.getElementById("pageNumber").innerText = actualPage;
        rebuildPagination();
        /* request.onload = function () {
          let dataArr = JSON.parse(this.response).data;
        }
        */

        processData(dummyData);

        // request.open('GET', 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=' + start + '&per_page=' + limit, true);
        // request.send();
    };

    function rebuildPagination() {
        document.getElementById("pageNumber").innerText = actualPage;
        const oldPage = document.getElementById("page");
        const page = document.createElement("div");
        page.setAttribute("id", "page");
        oldPage.replaceWith(page);

        let middle = (actualPage > 1) ? actualPage : actualPage + 1;
        let leftSibling = Math.max(1, middle - 1);
        let rightSibling = Math.min(numberOfPages, middle + 1);

        if (leftSibling > 1) {
            addButton(page, 1);
            if (leftSibling > 2) {
                addButton(page, "...");
            }
        }

        if (rightSibling === middle) {
            addButton(page, leftSibling - 1);
        }

        addButton(page, leftSibling);
        addButton(page, middle);

        if (rightSibling !== middle) {
            addButton(page, rightSibling);
        }

        if (numberOfPages - rightSibling > 1) {
            addButton(page, "...");
            addButton(page, 15);
        } else if (numberOfPages - rightSibling === 1) {
            addButton(page, 15);
        }
    }

    rebuildPagination();

    function addButton(parent, number, direction) {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        if (number === "...") {
            button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            actualPage = number;
            loadDoc();
        });
        button.innerHTML = number;

        parent.appendChild(button);
    }

    loadDoc(1);

    function processData(dataArr) {
        const table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("id", "table");
        const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

        for (let i in dataArr) {
            const row = document.createElement("tr");

            for (let attr in dataArr[i]) {
                if (dataArr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr !== "avatar") {
                    const td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML = dataArr[i]["" + attr];
                    row.appendChild(td);
                }
            }
            const avatarTD = document.createElement("td");

            if (dataArr[i].hasOwnProperty("avatar")) {
                const avatarImg = document.createElement("img");
                avatarImg.setAttribute("src", dataArr[i].avatar);
                avatarImg.style.maxWidth = "200px";
                avatarTD.appendChild(avatarImg);
            }
            row.appendChild(avatarTD);
            tbody.appendChild(row);
        }
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        document.getElementById("table").replaceWith(table);
    }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  tbody tr td {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="page">
</div>
<h1>
  Page <span id="pageNumber"></span>
</h1>
<table id="table">
</table>
```

Comment: `const row = document.createElement("row");` You mean `tr`

Comment: Can you please provide me a working demo of it because its not working for me and the pagination stages are different as well in your code. Following are the stages of pagination count which I want:- if 1 => 1 2 3 ... 15(last page) if 2 => 1 2 3 ...15 if 3 => 1 2 3 4 ... 15 if 4 => 1...3 4 5...15 if 15 =>1...13 14 15 if 14=>1... 13 14 15 if 13 => 1 ... 12 13 14 15 if 12 => 1 ... 11 12 13 ... 15. The pagination should work like this actually. Thank you!! geronimo678 @mplungjan

Comment: This is the working example of the fiddle of my code:- http://jsfiddle.net/8ondq07c/3 geronimo678 @mplungjan

Comment: @Nishant88277 I changed my code. The meaning of the limit variable in your code doesn't make sense, because it's about the max. elements per page. It think the code should help you. The requests didn't work, that's why I used dummy data. The further adaption on the code is on you.